# rails - Objects persisted by FactoryGirl are not available in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, factory-bot, database-cleaner

I am writing tests for my controllers in admin namespace. Using RSpec (3.5.0), FactoryGirl (4.8.0), DatabaseCleaner (1.5.3) and Mongoid (6.0.3).

The problem is that these test act strangely. When testing `GET index` request, objects produced by FactoryGirl are successfully created and persisted. However, the controller does not seem to find them.

I have three different controllers. 2 out of 3 have this problem and the third one works like a charm. The code is the same (except for naming) the only difference is that the resource for the working controller is nested.

The one for accessories works:

```
describe "GET #index", get: true do

    let (:accessory) { FactoryGirl.create(:accessory) }

    before do
      get :index, params: { category_id: accessory.category_id.to_s }, session: valid_session, format: :json
    end

    it "responses with OK status" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it "responses with a non-empty Array" do
      expect(json_body).to be_kind_of(Array)
      expect(json_body.length).to eq(1)
    end

    it "responses with JSON containing accessory" do
      expect(response.body).to be_json
      expect(json_body.first.with_indifferent_access).to match({
          id: accessory.to_param,
          name: 'Test accessory',
          description: 'This is an accessory',
          car_model: 'xv',
          model_year: '2013',
          images: be_kind_of(Array),
          category_id: accessory.category.to_param,
          dealer_id: accessory.dealer.to_param,
          url: be_kind_of(String)
        })
    end
  end
```

And the one for categories does not:

```
describe "GET #index", get: true do

    let (:category) { FactoryGirl.create(:category) }

    before do
      get :index, params: {}, session: valid_session, format: :json
    end

    it "responses with OK status" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end

    it "responses with a non-empty Array" do
      expect(json_body).to be_kind_of(Array)
      expect(json_body.length).to eq(1)
    end

    it "responses with JSON containing category" do
      expect(response.body).to be_json
      expect(json_body.first.with_indifferent_access).to match({
          id: category.to_param,
          name: 'Test category',
          image: be_kind_of(String),
          url: be_kind_of(String)
        })
    end
  end
```

As you can see the logic is the same: issuing a request in the `before` hook and using `let` to set the object.

Another strange thing is that `GET show` test for categories with the same logic works perfectly.

In these questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660341/records-created-with-factorygirl-not-available-in-controller), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001652/models-created-with-factorygirl-arent-available-in-controller)) they say it might be due to DatabaseCleaner strategy and one should use `truncation` instead of `transaction` strategy. Which I do since Mongoid allows only `truncation`. And I am also not using JavaScript-enabled tests and specifically told rspec to `use_transactional_fixtures = false`

RSpec config for FactoryGirl and DatabaseCleaner:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

I am able to make these tests pass by issuing request and creating an object in each example instead of using `before` and `let`. But I think it should work with them.

Controller index methods are default:

```
def index
  @thing = Thing.all
end
```

Do you have any thoughts on this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try `let!` instead of `let`.

Note that `let` is lazy-evaluated. Category data is generated when you call `category.to_param`. It does not exist in the `before` block.

See also https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Comment: Oh, right! Can't believe I haven't noticed that I am actually calling the object in the working examples. Thanks a lot, @zaru!